# Is declaring function within function for threading good programming style?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following code for click handler in my PyQT4 program:

```
def click_btn_get_info(self):
    task = self.window.le_task.text()
    self.statusBar().showMessage('Getting task info...')

    def thread_routine(task_id):
        order = self.ae.get_task_info(task_id)
        if order:
            info_str = "Customer: {email}\nTitle: {title}".format(**order)
            self.window.lbl_order_info.setText(info_str)
            self.statusBar().showMessage('Done')
        else:
            self.statusBar().showMessage('Authentication: failed!')

    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_routine, args=(task,))
    thread.start()
```

Is it a good practice to declare function in function for using with threads?

Comment: I'm not sure using threading.Thread with a PyQt4 class is a good practice. There are threading alternatives shipped with PyQt4.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: That's not true, and it's very dangerous advice. There's just one event loop, with one event queue, which delivers signals to `QObjects` by calling their `event` method. If you do something slow or blocking in an `event` handler on one object, you block the whole thread. See [Threads, Events, and QObjects](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects) for a better explanation.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you abarnert. I deleted my comment. I was clearly mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, yes, this is perfectly reasonable. However, the alternative of creating a separate method (or, for top-level code, a separate function) is *also* perfectly reasonable. And so is creating a `Thread` subclass. So, there's no rule saying to always do one of the three; there are different cases where each one seems more reasonable than the others, but there's overlap between those cases, so it's usually a judgment call.

As Maxime pointed out, you probably want to use Qt's threading, not native Python threading. Especially since you want to call methods on your GUI objects. The Qt docs article [Threads, Events and QObjects](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects) in the Qt documentation gives you an overview (although from a C++, not Python, viewpoint). And if you're using a `QThread` rather than a `threading.Thread`, it is much more common to use the OO method—define a subclass of `QThread` and override its `run` method than to define a function, which makes your question moot.

But if you do stick with Python threading, here's how I'd decide.

Pro separate method:

- You're doing this in a class method, rather than a function, and that the only state you want to share with the new thread is `self`.
- Non-trivial code, longer than the function it's embedded in.

Pro local function:

- Pretty specific to the info button callback; no one else will ever want to call it.

I'd probably make it a method, but I wouldn't complain about someone else's code that made it a local function.

In a different case—e.g., if the thread needed access to a local variable that had no business being part of the object, or if it were a trivial function I could write as an inline lambda, or if this were a top-level function sharing globals rather than a method sharing `self`, I'd go the other direction.